# React router, how to save transition and redirect upon successful login

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect the user to the login page it they attempt to access an endpoint that requires authentication, but I want to save the page they attempted to access so that once they login, I can redirect them to that page. In the older versions of react router, I believe you were able to do this, using a wrapper (example taken from [auth0](https://auth0.com/blog/adding-authentication-to-your-react-flux-app/)):

```
export default (ComposedComponent) => {
  return class AuthenticatedComponent extends React.Component {

    static willTransitionTo(transition) {
      // This method is called before transitioning to this component. If the user is not logged in, we’ll send him or her to the Login page.
      if (!LoginStore.isLoggedIn()) {
        transition.redirect('/login', {}, {'nextPath' : transition.path});
      }
    }

    ...

  }
}
```

And then in the action that gets called upon successfully authenticating with the API:

```
loginUser: (jwt) => {
    var savedJwt = localStorage.getItem('jwt');

    AppDispatcher.dispatch({
      actionType: LOGIN_USER,
      jwt: jwt
    });

    if (savedJwt !== jwt) {
      var nextPath = RouterContainer.get().getCurrentQuery().nextPath || '/';

      RouterContainer.get().transitionTo(nextPath);
      localStorage.setItem('jwt', jwt);
    }
  }
```

I know that in the new react router API, the first part can be done with

```
router.push({ pathname, query, state })
```

However, where is the place to access the state (in this case, `nextPath`)? I believe the `getCurrentQuery` function on the router has been deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`onEnter`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#onenternextstate-replace-callback) hook in the route definition ([demo](https://codepen.io/oridr22/pen/oLrvya?editors=1010)).

The Login page should include a reference to router in the props (wrapping it with react-router [`withRouter`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#withroutercomponent) HoC). In addition, the location prop should include the needed data to redirect back to the original location:

```
const Login = withRouter(({ router, location }) => (
  <div>
    <button type="click" onClick={() => {
        LoginStore.logIn();
        router.replace(location.state); // on login redirect back to the original location, by taking that location's details from the router state
      }}>Click to Login</button>
  </div>
));
```

The login onEnter handler should redirect to the Login page, and pass the original page details (`nextState`) in the the location state:

```
const redirectToLogin = (nextState, replace) => {
    if (!LoginStore.isLoggedIn()) {
      const { pathname, search, query, state } = nextState.location;
      replace({ pathname: '/login', state: { pathname, search, query, state } });
    }
};
```

Add `onEnter={ redirectToLogin  }` to routes that require login:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router>
    <Route path="/" component={MainLayout}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home} />
      <Route path="login" component={Login} />
      <Route path="page1" component={Page1} onEnter={ redirectToLogin } />
      <Route path="page2" component={Page2} onEnter={ redirectToLogin } />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```